# Hide by axis in the Graph Editor (multiple objects)

Tags: graph-editor

I would like to select multiple objects, then in the Graph Editor hide all curves except those belonging to a particular axis. I am looking for an automated method, not manual switching off the eye icons. For example hide everything but the Location X curve or Rotation Z etc. Makes sense? Is it possible?

Comment: This can be done manually by clicking on each unwanted strip's eye icon at extreme left.  You can also block inadvertant access to each by padlocking strips. (the padlock icon, again at the left)   Those items you haven't selected in the 3D window won't show in the Graph editor.

Comment: Oh, I am looking for an automated method since I have hundreds of objects I want to edit at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using 2.8 but i believe it's the same in 2.79 , in the graph editor you'll find magnifier with filed string called "f-curve live filtering string" type there what they called  like "X Location or just X Loc" etc and you'll get only the axis you want...u can see on the side how the string is written like rotation is Euler, type that and you'll get only the rotation of all objects...etc :)

Comment: Yes, that works!

Answer (score 1):

In 3.3, I have collections that I want to adjust all its objects at once, but only along one axis. I managed to quickly filter the axes by typing the name of the axis (1) in the search box (2).

[image]

I can now drag-select around the node I want to modify in the graph, only the filtered axis (3) is affected.

[image]

At the top left, I am typing `x location`, as per the static screenshot.